# The Boolean algebra of all almost invariant subsets of an uncountable locally finite group is contained in every Sub-Boolean that separates points

Tags: gr.group-theory, boolean-algebras

Let $G$ be a group. A subset $A\subset G$ is said to be **almost right invariant** if $A\mathbin\Delta A\cdot g$ is finite for all $G$. The family of all almost right invariant subsets $\mathcal{B}_G$ of $G$ is a sub-Boolean algebra of the power set  $\mathcal{P}(G)$.

Assume that $G$ is uncountable locally finite group, and $\mathcal{B}$ is a sub-Boolean algebra of the power set  $\mathcal{P}(G)$ that separates points (that is for all $g\neq h\in G$ there exists $A\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $g\in A$ and $h\in A^c$).

I would like to prove that $\mathcal{B}$  contains a sub-Boolean algebra that is isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}_G$.

Answer (score 1):

Not if $|G|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

It is a theorem of D. Holt [H] that for an uncountable locally finite group $G$, the Boolean of (right) almost invariant subsets is reduced to that $W_G$ consisting of finite and cofinite subsets in $G$. (This theorem was previously obtained by Scott and Sonneborn [SS] for uncountable locally finite abelian groups.)

Given this, the question becomes equivalent to the following one, unrelated to group theory:

> Let $X$ be an uncountable set. Is it true that every Boolean subalgebra of the power set of $X$, separating points, contains $|X|$ pairwise disjoint nonzero elements.

And indeed, on the reals let $A$ be the set of subsets that are finite union of left-closed, right-open intervals. This is a Boolean subalgebra; it separates points but has no uncountable subset of pairwise disjoint elements.

[SS] *Scott, W. R.; Sonneborn, L. M.*, [**Translations of infinite subsets of a group**](https://doi.org/10.4064/cm-10-2-217-220), Colloq. Math. 10, 217-220 (1963). [ZBL0122.27201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0122.27201)..

[H] *Holt, D. F.*, [**Uncountable locally finite groups have one end**](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/13.6.557), Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 13, 557-560 (1981). [ZBL0477.20015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0477.20015).

Comment: Reading this again now, I don't see where I'm using Holt's result at all. The only point is that, regardless of $G$, the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}_G$ contains $|G|$ pairwise disjoint nonzero elements, and that indeed the example $A$ given by intervals has no room for this.

Answer (score -1):

An extended comment:
Regardless of $X$ being uncountable or not, as long  as it is infinite the Stone space of $W_X$ is the one-point compactification of $X$ (as a discrete space). Knowing that the Stone space of a sub-Boolean algebra of the power set separating points is a compactification $Y$ of $X$; and that for a compactification $Y$ of $X$, the family $\mathcal{B}_Y:=\{A\cap X:A$ is clopen subset of $Y\}$ (assuming that $X\subset Y$) is a sub-Boolean algebra separating  points; and that a compactification $Z$ of $X$ dominates $Y$ if and only if $\mathcal{B}_Z$ contains a sub-Boolean algebra isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}_Y$, we can deduce that $W_X$ is isomorphic to sub-Boolean algebra of any sub-Boolean algebra separating points.

My question is: Is there a direct proof to the fact that every sub-Boolean algebra of the power set of $G$ ($G$ is an uncountable locally finite group) separating points contains a copy of $\mathcal{B}_G$ (the sub-Boolean algebra of all almost right invariant subsets)?

Comment: Since this is your question and is not an answer, shouldn't you rather edit your question to incorporate this?

Comment: I wanted to add a comment to your answer, I don't know if it is a good idea to incorporate the comment into my question.

Comment: There's no direct proof of this fact since I said in my answer that this fact is false.